# convert QTime into seconds

Tags: c++, qt

How do I convert a `QTime` into seconds?  I've set the time manually with `time.setHMS(0,1,0);`

Now when I convert this variable `time` into an `integer`, I want to get 60 seconds. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Your title says the input is `hh:mm:ss` format, but then the question body says the input is a `QTime`.  Are you trying to convert from `QTime` to the total number of elapsed seconds?

Comment: I'm trying to convert QTime into seconds. When I see the output of QTime variable I get hh:mm:ss format, that's why I said in title that I want to convert hh:mm:ss into seconds. Sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: The original question did not mention *since midnight*, when did that become a requirement, or is that just to make the question more interesting?

Comment: How were you "seeing the output of QTime variable"?  [This member](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html#toString) says "If format is empty, the default format "hh:mm:ss" is used."

Comment: @user315052 I'd added it since times only make sense relative to some baseline and converting a time to seconds makes no sense without a baseline.  `QTime` seems to have an implied baseline of midnight, so I had added that for clarity, but I've now removed it again

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int seconds = QTime(0, 0, 0).secsTo(time);
```

Comment: When I run this I get 0 and I should get 60. This is my code:

time.setHMS(0,1,0);
int seconds = QTime().secsTo(time);
qDebug() << seconds;

Comment: @Alen: This works for me. Did you try sending it to `cout` instead? [Here is my program.](http://pastebin.com/XGXjLdAx)

Comment: @Alen: You compiled my test program? What did your compile and link line look like?

Comment: I just copied your lines into my main.cpp file and compiled.

Comment: @Alen: You can try: `QTime(0, 0, 0).secsTo(time)` instead.

Comment: Or just time.hour() * 3600 + time.minute() * 60 + time.seconds(). A bit more verbose, but straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `int seconds = QTime(0,0).secsTo(time);` It works in Qt 5.3.0